# Javascript compare objects having functions using lodash isEqual

Tags: javascript, lodash

how to compare two objects for equality if they have functions? lodash's isEqual works really well until functions are thrown in:

```
_.isEqual({
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}, {
    b: 2,    
    a: 1
});

// -> true

_.isEqual({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: function () {
        return 1;
    }
}, {
    a: 1,    
    b: 2,
    c: function () {
          return 1;
    }
});

// -> false
```

Comment: two anonymous function have two different prototypes, so two different objects!

Comment: It really depends on what you are going to compare. Best solution would be to create a hash unique per object and compare it, or, knowing the structure, make an equal function for that particular object.

Comment: Even though the functions do the same, they will never be equal. Do you want to ignore the functions and compare?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you want to compare functions? If you only care about comparing every property that isn't a function, this is easy to do with lodash:

```js
var o1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: function() { return 1; } },
    o2 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: function() { return 1; } };

_.isEqual(o1, o2)
// → false

_.isEqual(_.omit(o1, _.functions(o1)), _.omit(o2, _.functions(o2)));
// → true
```

The [functions()](https://lodash.com/docs#functions) function returns a list of function properties, and using [omit()](https://lodash.com/docs#omit), you can get rid of them.

Comment: Since I was comparing complex objects, I needed to skip all functions: const isEqualExcludingFunctions = (a, b) => isEqualWith(a, b, (a, b) => (typeof a === 'function' || typeof b === 'function')?true:undefined); replace "||" with "&&" for a slightly stricter compare.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for deep comparisons. If the function is nested, it won't be found by `functions` and won't be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I tried:

```
_.isEqual(o1, o2, function(val1, val2) {
  if(_.isFunction(val1) && _.isFunction(val2)) {
    return val1.toString() === val2.toString();
  }
})
```

Lodash supports a `customizer` function which allows you to write your own equality checks. This seems to be a good enough test to see if the functions are character by character the same.

Comment: `_.isEqualWith` has this third `customizer` parameter https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqualWith

Comment: From the docs (helped me understand this answer better): 'If customizer returns undefined, comparisons are handled by the method instead.'

Answer (score 2):

Try [`isEqualWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith) instead:

```js
import { isEqualWith, isFunction } from 'lodash-es'

const o1 = { fn() {} }

const o2 = { fn() {} }

const equal = isEqualWith(o1, o2, (v1, v2) =>
  // if `customizer` returns `undefined`, comparisons are handled by the method instead
  isFunction(v1) && isFunction(v2) ? `${v1}` === `${v2}` : undefined,
)

console.log({ equal }) // { equal: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

As the lodash documentation states:

> Functions and DOM nodes are not supported.

https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Comment: They've since clarified this to `Functions and DOM nodes are compared by strict equality, i.e. ===.` I didn't check to see if the behavior actually changed or just the comment.